# In C, how do you use a struct in the main function that was declared in a header file?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, header-files

In C, I need to declare a struct linked list in a header file. Within the main of my .c file, how do I declare a new instance of my struct? Also should I use typedef for my struct?

Comment: You need to be clearer what you want help with. Give us some example you do not understand.

Comment: And no, you don't need type-aliases (`typedef`) for structures, or anything really, it's mostly to make some complicated types easier to read and write.

Answer (score 2):

In your header:

```
struct mystruct
{
int a;
int b;
};
```

in .c file *include* (`#include "header.h"`) the header, then use in main:

```
struct mystruct obj1;
obj1.a=0;
obj1.b=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your header file add the definition and typedef

```
typedef struct linked_list_node_st {
    int val;
    struct linked_list_node_st *next;
} Linked_List_Node;
```

In main.c, call the struct using the typedef.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "structure.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Linked_List_Node *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof(Linked_List_Node));
    node->next = 0;
    node->val = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good, but for clarity I would use `struct linked_list_node_st` for the structure, and `Linked_List_Node` for the type (i.e. `typedef struct linked_list_node_st Linked_List_Node;` ....); using the same identifier for the structure tag and the type name could be confusing for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

U have struct in header, and want that struct in main.c?
**Just include it with #include "header.h" directive in your main.c, and start to use struct.**

You use typedef when u want to make "your variable" in `c`, like:

```
typedef int INTEGER;
INTEGER number;
```

So u use typedef for closer indentify your struct, for you or for readers.

Comment: Actually your `INTEGER` example is not very good. For readability better use `int`. However `<stdint.h>` defines interesting integral types (e.g. `uint32_t` or `intptr_t`) in C.

Comment: I just took "visual" example, or one of purpose of typedef.